# Why don't the circles show up?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I built some SVG with d3.js but nothing is displayed. Why? Here is part of code:

```
<svg width="863" height="863" id="svgId">
<g transform="translate(431.5,431.5)">
    <g class="asdf" r="421.5">
        <circle transform="translate(0,0)" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="asdf" r="127.6354829132969">
        <circle transform="translate(-118.50486492278469,167.13470131539657)" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></circle>
    </g>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set the radius (r attribute) on the `<g>` element where it does nothing and not on the `<circle>` element where it's required. What you need is this...

```
<svg width="863" height="863" id="svgId">
<g transform="translate(431.5,431.5)">
    <g class="asdf">
        <circle r="421.5" transform="translate(0,0)" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></circle>
    </g>
    <g class="asdf">
        <circle  r="127.6354829132969" transform="translate(-118.50486492278469,167.13470131539657)" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0);"></circle>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```